# equating two sets in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

Suppose I have two lists
`a = [2,3,4]` and `b=[2,3,4]`
Then why

```
>>> set(a) in set(b)
False
```

although

```
>>> set(a) == set(b)
True
```

Comment: The set doesn't contain a `set(2, 3, 4)`, it contains integers, `2`, `3`, `4`.

Comment: `>>> set(a) in [set(b)]` this would give you True

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are testing if `set(b)` contains the literal set object. `set(b)` doesn't contain such an object.

If you want to test if `set(a)` is a subset or equal, use `<=`:

```
>>> set(a) <= set(b)
True
```

or use the [`set.issubset()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset):

```
>>> set(a).issubset(b)
True
```

Either option also returns `True` for smaller sets where all elements are also contained in `b`:

```
>>> set([2, 3]) <= set(b)
True
>>> set([2, 3]).issubset(b)
True
>>> set([2, 3, 42]) <= set(b)
False
>>> set([2, 3, 42]).issubset(b)
False
```

Answer (score 2):

The set doesn't contain a `set(2, 3, 4)`, it contains integers, `2`, `3`, and `4`.

You could ask whether individual integers are in the set:

```
>>> 2 in set(b)
True

>>> 3 in set(b)
True

>>> 4 in set(b)
True
```

The [documentation for set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) shows to check for containment you can do it [two ways](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset):

```
>>> set(a) <= set(b)
True
```

or

```
>>> set(a).issubset(set(b))
True
```

Comment: Then how can you check if one set contains the other

Comment: @PalashAhuja `>>> set(a) == set(b)` will check whether one set contains the other. For example `>>> set([1,2,3]) ==set([1,3,2])`  returns True.

Comment: @TanveerAlam: no, that only tests if the sets are **equal**. `set([1, 2])` contains elements that are also in `b`, for example.

Comment: @TanveerAlam What if `a = [2,3]` then ?

Comment: Yeah set's subset would be correct. Thanks Martijin.

Answer (score 1):

Testing if one set contains another can be done with comparison operator or with .issuperset

```py
>>> set([2, 3, 4]) >= set([2, 3])
True
>>> set([2, 3, 4]).issuperset(set([2, 3]))
True
```

See [8.7. sets — Unordered collections of unique elements](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)